# How to rotate animation my button when click in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

these are my declaration for my DoubleAnimation and storyboard

```
private Storyboard openmenurotateSB;

DoubleAnimation openMenuRotate = new DoubleAnimation();
openMenuRotate.From = 0;
openMenuRotate.To = 90;
openMenuRotate.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
openMenuRotate.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
openMenuRotate.AutoReverse = true;
openmenurotateSB = new Storyboard();
openmenurotateSB.Children.Add(openMenuRotate);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(openMenuRotate, OpenMenuButton.Name);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(openMenuRotate, new PropertyPath(RotateTransform.AngleProperty));
```

when click, begin rotate animation

```
private void OpenMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            openmenurotateSB.Begin(OpenMenuButton);
        }
```

There is no any error or exception, it just does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Xing Yik

Comment: Hi Clemens, these are my assignation of rotatetransform to the button
OpenMenuButton.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(0);
OpenMenuButton.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

Answer (score 2):

A `RotateTransform` should be assigned to either the `RenderTransform` or the `LayoutTransform` property of the Button.

```
<Button Content="Open Menu" Click="OpenMenu_Click"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform"/>
    </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```

You do not need to use a Storyboard. Just directly animate the RotateTransform.

```
private void OpenMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var animation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        To = 90,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
        AutoReverse = true
    };

    rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(
        RotateTransform.AngleProperty, animation);
}
```

or if you don't want to assign an `x:Name` to the RotateTransform or have assigned the RenderTransform property in code behind:

```
((UIElement)sender).RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(
    RotateTransform.AngleProperty, animation);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Clemens! Assigning rotatetrasnform with name in rendertransform does not work but in layouttransform and the origin of rotating is inaccurate even though we have set the value to 0.5,0.5 
However, without assigning the name to RotateTransform in RenderTransform, it works.
I am so confused right now, if you have explanation for it, I would like to hear about it too

Comment: LayoutTransform does not have an origin like RenderTransform. Why assigning a name to the RotateTransform does not work for you is unclear. The example here does however work.